# Solving recurrence relation effiency class?

Tags: performance, substitution, recurrence

I am calculating the effiency class of this

R(n) = 2R(n−1)+2.

with the base case of  R(1) = 1

using backwards substitution.

My equations came out to

4R(n-2) + 6

8R(n-3) + 14

16R(n-4) +30

I don't see how i can get an equation from this... Is it incorrect?

Comment: I think you should ask this question on a Mathematics forum, like http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer because this looks like homework, but let’s say that each step of the relation doubled in complexity, so f(1) = 1, f(2) = 2, f(3) = 4, f(4) = 8, and so on.  What kind of growth is this?  What is the equation for f(n)?

Now, suppose it was g(n) = 2g(n-1) + 1, with g(1) = 1.  We see that the sequence is 1, 3, 7, 15, etc, which looks a lot like 2^n-1, so let’s check our intuition.  For g(n) = a2^n + b, we get 2g(n-1) + 1 = 2[a2^(n-1) + b] + 1 = a2^n + 2b + 1.  We solve g(n) = a2^n + b = a2^n + 2b + 1 for b and get b = -1.  Now we need to solve for a using the boundary condition.  g(1) = 1 = a2^1 - 1.  In this case, a = 1 and therefore g = 2^n - 1, as we guessed.

Does this example show the method to use to solve your problem?